# In Python3, is it possible to merge two objects into a new object so that references to the original objects now refer to the new object?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary `d = {1: A, 2: A, 3: B, 4: B}` and then I have an operation that merges object A and object B into a new object say `C = merge(A, B)`. Is it possible to make all the keys that referenced A and B to now reference C in constant time?

```
# pseudocode
d = {1: A, 2: A, 3: B, 4: B}
C = merge(A, B)
# At this point I want (d[1] is C) == True and (d[3] is C) == True
```

Is something like this possible in Python3?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by merging objects? How do you want to merge them?

Comment: @ARK1375 e.g. If the objects represent intervals A = [1, 10], B = [10, 20]. C = merge(A, B) = [1, 20]

Comment: And why do you require identity? If ```A``` and ```B``` are mutable objects, e.g. lists, you can manipulate them to be equal, even if they have different object IDs (```A==B``` but not ```A is B```

Comment: I guess it is possible to use a trick, however, objects A and B will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this manually, probably using a separate `dict` that represents the relation implied by the merge.

```
d = {1: A, 2: A, 3: B, 4: B}
C = merge(A, B)
merger = {A: C, B: C}
d = {k: merger[v] for k, v in d.items()}
```

The references to `A` and `B` don't "know" anything about the process that creates `C`.

In particular, `merge` itself doesn't know who else might have references to its arguments, and certainly wouldn't know how to update `d` if it did.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I'm saying is super hacky and I would not recommend doing something like this at all. **Use this at your own risk**.

First of all, you should know that there are no real way of combing two objects with each other as the *objects* themselves are quite different from one another.
However, by defining your own `merge` function, there is a work around it. See the code below:

```py
import sys
# define the merge function as merge

def merge_obj( obj_a , obj_b , new_object_name ):
    new_object = merge(obj_a , obj_b)
    flag_obj_a = True
    flag_obj_b = True

    for instance_name in dir(sys.modules[__name__]):

        if flag_obj_a and getattr(sys.modules[__name__] , instance_name) == obj_a:
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__] , instance_name , new_object)
            flag_obj_a = False
        if flag_obj_b and getattr(sys.modules[__name__] , instance_name) == obj_b:
            setattr(sys.modules[__name__] , instance_name , new_object)
            flag_obj_b = False
```

Now you can use the `merge_obj` to merge your objects and make sure that in the original module, both previous objects get updated.

*Note that this only works for the objects that are defined inside a modeule.*